# xslt for choosing the element from subset of the selected node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a XML where i need to select specific elements from all nodes and for the selected elements i need to select the values from subset of the node. The structure of actual XML looks like this-

```
<Host> 
  <Node> 
    <element1>type0</element1>
    <element2>Fruits0</element2>
  </Node>
  <Node>
    <element1>type1</element1>
    <element2>Fruits1</element2>
  </Node>
  <Node>
      <element1>type2</element1>
      <element2>
        <Namelist>
          <Names>
            <element2>fruit2</element2>  
            <Node>
              <element1>type3</element1>
              <element2>Fruits3</element2>
            </Node> 
          </Names>
        </Namelist>
      </element2>
  </Node>
  <Node>
    <element1>type4</element1>
    <element2>Fruits4</element2>
  </Node>  
  <Node>
    <element1>type5</element1>
    <element2>Fruits5</element2>
  </Node>
</Host>
```

Now the expected output XML is as follows-

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1"> 
  <tr>
    <td>type0</td>
    <td>Fruits0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type1</td>
    <td>Fruits1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type2</td>
    <td>Fruits2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type3</td>
    <td>Fruits3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type4</td>
    <td>Fruits4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type5</td>
    <td>Fruits5</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</body>  
</html>
```

The XSLT written is as follows-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"   
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
   <xsl:for-each select="Host">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Node">
    <xsl:sort select="element1" />
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="element1" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="element2" /></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is not as expected -

```
<html>
<body>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>type0</td>
    <td>Fruits0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type1</td>
    <td>Fruits1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type2</td>
    <td>Fruits2Fruits3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type3</td>
    <td>Fruits3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type4</td>
    <td>Fruits4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>type5</td>
    <td>Fruits5</td>
  </tr>
</table> 
</body>  
</html>
```

I want to format the output for element having data `<element2>Fruits2Fruits3</element2>` which should not include child node data. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please fix your XML example and make it well-formed.

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k I have modified xml example and output. All I need is for element where <element2>Fruits2</element2> should not include child node data.

Comment: You need to properly close `/host/Node[3]`. Also, some elements start with `element` and some start with `Element` (capital `E`). Is this inconsistency on purpose or just typos?

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k, sorry it is a typo and I corrected it.  Also for /host/Node[3] the node is same as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="element2"/></td>
```

to:

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="(.//element2[text()])[1]"/></td>
```